# How do I properly parse the JSON from this local JSON?

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a lot of trouble correctly parsing the JSON from a local JSON file, storing it into an array and then displaying it in my view.

My app does not crash. The labels I have on the screen (4 buttons and 1 label) simply do not change values. They just get those sample values I added in there "Question 1", "Question 2", etc...

How do I get it to display the values from my JSON file ? It looks like [this](http://numbersapi.com/1..100/trivia?fragment&json)

```
/* Question label storyboard outlet */
@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!

// Answer button storyboard outlets
@IBOutlet weak var topLeftButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var topRightButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomLeftButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomRightButton: UIButton!

/* Questions Set */
var questionObjects = NSMutableOrderedSet(capacity: 100)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getQuestionsFromJSONFile()
    displayQuestion(0, jsonObjectsSet: questionObjects)

    let string = "some Random Question"
    questionLabel.text = string.capitalizeFirstCharacter
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func getQuestionsFromJSONFile() {
    var questionsJSONData: NSData? = nil
    do {
        let pathToQuestionsJSONFile = try NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Trivia_100-199", ofType: "json")
        do {
            questionsJSONData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: pathToQuestionsJSONFile!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
            let questionsJSONContent = JSON(data: questionsJSONData!)
            if let object : [String:[String:AnyObject]] = questionsJSONContent.object as? [String:[String:AnyObject]] {
                parseJSONContentIntoObjects(object)
            }

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        /*
        if let questionsJSONContent = JSON(data: questionsJSONData!) as? [String: [String : AnyObject]] {
            parseJSONContentIntoObjects(questionsJSONContent) // PSE: Potential Source of Error
        }
        */
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        print(error.localizedFailureReason)
        print(error.localizedRecoveryOptions)
        print(error.localizedRecoverySuggestion)
    }
}

func parseJSONContentIntoObjects(jsonData: [String: [String : AnyObject]]) {
    var questionHasAProperAnswer = false // indicator to determine if a proper answer was provided by the API for this specific question
    let jsonObjects = NSMutableOrderedSet(capacity: 100)
    for (questionAnswer,questionPropertiesSubJson):(String,[String:AnyObject]) in jsonData {
        if let questionObject = Question(questionObjectSubJson: questionPropertiesSubJson) as? Question { // All parsing code is in the model file (Question.swift)
        if let answerText = questionObject.questionAnswer as? String {
            let questionExclusionKeywords = ["the Earth probably", "boring", "uninteresting", "unremarkable", "we do not know", "nothing", "remarkable", "a number for which", "missing a fact"]
            for questionExclusionKeyword in (questionExclusionKeywords as? [String])! {
                questionHasAProperAnswer = !answerText.containsString(questionExclusionKeyword)
             /*
                if questionHasAProperAnswer {
                    jsonObjects.addObject(questionObject)
                }
            }

            if answerText.containsAny(questionExclusionKeywords) {
                jsonObjects.addObject(questionObject)
                }
            */
            jsonObjects.addObject(questionObject)
            }
        }
    }
    questionObjects = jsonObjects
    if questionObjects.count == 0 {
        let fillerObject = Question(questionText: "Some question", questionAnswer: 1234, questionFalseAnswer1: "333", questionFalseAnswer2: "444", questionFalseAnswer3: "555")
        questionObjects.addObject(fillerObject)
    }

}
}

func displayQuestion(questionIndex: Int, jsonObjectsSet: NSMutableOrderedSet) {
    if let specificQuestionObject = jsonObjectsSet.objectAtIndex(questionIndex) as? Question {
        if let questionText = specificQuestionObject.questionText {
            questionLabel.text = questionText
        }
        if let questionAnswer = specificQuestionObject.questionAnswer as? String {
            let capitalizedQuestionAnswer = questionAnswer.capitalizeFirstCharacter
            topLeftButton.titleLabel?.text = capitalizedQuestionAnswer
        }
        bottomLeftButton.titleLabel?.text = "Some false answer"
        topRightButton.titleLabel?.text = "Some other false answer"
        bottomRightButton.titleLabel?.text = "Another random false answer"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more detail? Can you describe the debugging have you done so far? How far along do things go as expected? Which specific methods/lines are definitely not working as you expect? Do any errors print?

Comment: you want parse jason data from json file right ?

Comment: @AaronBrager Thanks for replying. I have not really been able to make any useful conclusions from debugging. I just don't understand why the questionObjects NSMutableOrderedSet is not being populated correctly. I made a video to show you what exactly is going on. https://youtu.be/INVTDEJ8ZqY